# Is there a way to get a sample of non-login users of your product?

Tags: user-research, login

I have an issue that my users have problems with the sign-up page and many of my users spend much time using the product without login.

I plan to interview some of them, but I don't know how to get to these users.

Is there a way to get a sample of them?

Comment: How do you know users are having problems with sign-up? Is this just based on the number of users using the product without logging in?

Comment: You might consider doing observational studies, like usability tests, rather than interviews. That way you can see what's going on rather than asking people to remember what went on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting the question that you have a custom software product which you are developing, that offers some functionality with and some without logging in.

You could provide either a chat window (e.g. in a discreet popup element) offering a possibility to talk to the product team or a questionnaire to tell about the motivation for using the product without logging in.

If there are functions that would identify the user albeit not logging in - most likely user inputting their email address at some point - you could contact the users directly for feedback.

If you know there are some problems with the sign-up page, one approach would be to provide some tips in the difficult phases, or offering the aforementioned chat support on that page, too.

Of course, if and when you know what the problems are, just fix them and iterate.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to spend your time and resources fixing the signup procedure, not contacting users (at least not yet).

If many users are being lost at signup, then there may be some issues you can fix with the form. Have a coworker, friend, or anyone without prior knowledge of the form attempt to fill it out, and see where they fall short.

If after investigation there appears to be nothing wrong with the form, there could be other reasons users aren't signing up. Two examples:

- What is the main incentive of signing up (to the user)? Plenty of products don't require signup (YouTube, Reddit, SoundCloud). A significant portion of their traffic are unregistered users.
- How long are users typically on the product? If it's a quick visit, there not much reason for them to sign up.

The best solution to this is to compartment features to certain users. StackExchange (this site) is great at doing that. Browsing is free, but participating requires an account.